# Remove index.php for multiple domains in htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, htaccess

I have a multistore magento setup using domain aliases. 
How do I remove the index.php from the domain alias sites in the htaccess file?
Below is my current code, which only removes it from the main site.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This might be related to your vhosts config and not to Magento itself.

Comment: I have disabled the redirect for the domain alias through the plesk panel. I am using the htaccess to define the multistore environments. What vhost config are you referring to and where can I check it in the plesk panel?

Comment: 1. Stop using plesk. Its not going to allow you to configure a server to the extent necessary to run magento well.
2. Your domain aliases may not be picking up the .htaccess at all. As a quick test, try adding a redirect rule and see if it gets picked up on the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating separate folders for each store, then symlinking `app, includes, js, lib, media, skin and var`. This allows you to manage your `.htaccess` and `index.php` independently for each domain.

It sounds like you are trying to do this in cPanel so this is probably the best approach.

http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/#addon-domain-method

EDIT:
Just saw your comment that you are using Plesk. It might be a little different but this approach should still work.

Comment: I would prefer to not create extra folders.

Comment: This can be avoided, and should be whenever possible so that code duplication isn't necessary (multiple index.php and .htaccess files to manage).

Comment: @MattDunbar, How do you manage environment vars if not via htaccess or index.php? I don't think he has the ability to edit the vhost to add the SetEnv from the plesk dashboard. Manual edits to the vhost will be overwrite the next time the dashboard saves a vhost setting. This approach is the same that both Crucial and Nexcess use. If you are running separate stores use will likely need to manage separate htaccess files anyways. You could probably get away with symlinks the index.php file though.

Comment: @DanielSmith There are conditionals available in .htaccess (SetEnvIf). Also, plesk shouldn't be seen as a reasonable option for managing a Magento Server, its too limiting for all of the configuration tweaks necessary for Magento to run well.

Comment: @MattDunbar, personally I would not use Plesk as it adds unneeded overhead. It is however a reasonable option for running a Magento server and can be properly configured to run as such. OP's question was pertaining to configuration on a Plesk system, not a request for a hosting recommendation.

Comment: @DanielSmith I didn't make a hosting recommendation, I made an architecture recommendation that would alleviate the above issue while avoiding code duplication. As far as plesk goes though - to run a Magento site well there are various things to consider such as code pools (so that you can limit resources and stop an admin reindex from taking down the server) which you absolutely can not do with a Plesk setup. You might be able to get by, but you can't do what I'd consider a good production setup.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your insight. Due to all the "snow days", I have had some delays in working on this issue. I will take all into consideration and continue to try resolve this issue and let you know my solutions/findings.